# How to create priorities list and change them without leaving any gaps

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a simple script for google spreadsheet.

The code should work as follows: it should be a priority list, which can be simply edited. For example I have a list of 7 tasks and want to change the priority of one task. My code simply looks for values greater or eqauls then the value I put in a cell and increments them by 1. So at the end the last task has priority 8 and I have only 7 tasks, so there is one gap somewhere.

Here is what I've already done:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var numRowsWithData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();
  var cellEdited = range.getA1Notation();

  if (columnOfCellEdited === 2) {

    var valueOfEditedCell = range.getValue();

    for (var i = 2; i <=numRowsWithData; i++) {

      var rangeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
      var currentCell = rangeSheet.getCell(i, 2);
      var currentValue = currentCell.getValue(); 

      if(currentValue >= valueOfEditedCell) {
        if(cellEdited == currentCell.getA1Notation()){
            continue;
        }
        currentCell.setValue(currentValue+1);
      };

    }
  };
};
```

This script works, but I've got some missing numbers, because every time I add 1 to the current value.
How to edit it to have all the numbers in proper order, without any missing ones?

I know it's not very complicated, but I don't have any idea for now:/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Completely rewritten answer, following clarification of the question.

This function reads all of the existing priorities, including the new entry. Any existing value greater than the new one is incremented by 1. An array is used to store the row on which each value occurs. The array is then looped over, skipping any undefined entries (missing numbers), and renumbering those that do exist starting from 1.

This doesn't change the order of the rows. It simply renumbers the second column.

Where possible I've left your original code intact, and re-used your approach in the new bit.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var numRowsWithData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();
  var cellEdited = range.getA1Notation();

  if (columnOfCellEdited === 2) {
    var valueOfEditedCell = range.getValue();

    // get snapshot of current priorities
    var priorityRows = [];
    for (var row = 2; row <=numRowsWithData; row++) {
      var rangeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
      var currentCell = rangeSheet.getCell(row, 2);
      var currentValue = currentCell.getValue();
      if(currentValue >= valueOfEditedCell && cellEdited !== currentCell.getA1Notation()) {
        currentValue++;
      };
      priorityRows[currentValue] = row;
    }

    // renumber priorities
    var newPriority = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < priorityRows.length; i++) {
      var row = priorityRows[i];
      if (row) {
        var rangeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
        var currentCell = rangeSheet.getCell(row, 2);
        currentCell.setValue(newPriority++); 
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I mean, when I have 7 tasks to do with priority 1 to 7, then I set priority of the first task to for example "3" I have the priorities starting from 2. Of course I understand why, but I want to have priorities as a list starting from 1, without any gaps.